# How i can connect to bitcoin core light server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Need a bunch of Laravel + Bitcoin Core. Need a light version of bitcoin bark. Installed as follows:

sudo apt-get install build-essential && sudo apt-get install libtool autotools-dev autoconf & & sudo apt-get install libssl-dev && sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev && bitcoin && sudo apt-get update && bitdoin & mkdir ~ / .bitcoin / && cd ~ / .bitcoin / && nano bitcoin.conf

Config

proxy = 127.0.0.1: 9050 
rpcbind = 127.0.0.1 
rpcuser = user 
rpcpassword = password 
rpcthreads = 30 
testnet = 0 
rpcport = 143 
server = 1 
datadir = / root / .bitcoin / base / 
shrinkdebuglog = 1 prune = 551 lang = ru_RU 
printtoconsole = 1 server = 1

And how can I connect to this server now?
Run - bitcoind --daemon